# Border color opacity

Tags: html, css

My button css like this

```
.btn {   
   background: #3a4446;   
   background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3a4446, #0a0b0c);
   background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3a4446, #0a0b0c);
   background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3a4446, #0a0b0c);
   background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3a4446, #0a0b0c);
   background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3a4446, #0a0b0c);
   -webkit-border-radius: 11;
   -moz-border-radius: 11;
   border-radius: 11px;
   font-family: Arial;
   color: #ffffff;
   font-size: 20px;
   padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
   border: solid 5px;
   border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
   text-decoration: none; 
}
```

I want to reduce opacity of border color i added color as rgba mode but some issues please help

Comment: Please provide a reduced example as a fiddler: jsfiddle.net. Thanks.

Comment: I works already, what you need? http://jsfiddle.net/7n7YK/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hope it will help you

```
   .class {
border: 1px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, .5);
-webkit-background-clip: padding-box; /* for Safari */
background-clip: padding-box; /* for IE9+, Firefox 4+, Opera, Chrome */
 }
```